Solana websocket listen logs duplicate
I'm writing a script to listen to event emitted on Solana, but when listening, sometime the event is emitted twice at 2 different slots and timestamp. But when I go to solscan.io, I only see transaction on the second slot. Can anyone explain why?
This is my code and the result:
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), { commitment: 'finalized' });

const PROGRAM_ID = new anchor.web3.PublicKey(
  "7SEu4aJPXs24eLzF893T6SsnhzXGxC6KJZW23paGTqfK",
);
const program = new anchor.Program(
  IDLVaultDeposit as anchor.Idl,
  PROGRAM_ID,
  { connection }
);

const listenerMyEvent = program.addEventListener('TokenDeposited', (event, slot, signature) => {
  console.log("Signature: ", signature);
  console.log("Slot: ", slot);
  console.log("Event: ", event);
});



Thanks.

This looks like it could be a bug on the websocket server. I don't see any issues mentioned about this, but it might be known unfortunately. In the meantime, you can keep a little cache of recent signatures and deduplicate any that you see
